# How fix problem with reply comment in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I searched for a long time in Google, I did not find anything, I have a problem with comments. Whn i try adding reply comment, replying comment adds to another post. All replying comments adding to only one post.

How i can fix this issue ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell you what's wrong if you don't show any code that you have and tell us what you've tried to solve it so far.

Comment: @DirkScholten which code i must share ? i connect simple wp comment template for single, comment works, but when i reply any comment, it adds reply comment one single post

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem

```
if( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
```